# Is the subtrahend in the Nernst equation related to ohmic drop?

Tags: electrochemistry

Let us consider the Nernst equation $$E= E^\circ -\frac{2.303RT}{nF} \log Q$$ which once at $\pu{298.15 K}$, is the equivalent  of $$E= E^\circ - \frac{0.059}{n} \log Q .$$

Does the part of the Nernst equation $-\frac{0.059}{n} \log Q$ address Ohmic drop? In other words, is $-\frac{0.059}{n} \log Q$ related to solution (electrolyte) resistance of an electrochemical cell?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! If you have questions about how to beautify your posts, have a look at the [help]. Do you want to know more about this site, please take the [tour].
I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). Please do not use markup in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Answer (score 3):

In short: No.

The Nernst equation describes the thermodynamic equilibrium state. By definition, there is no current flowing through the cell. Therefore, there is no ohmic drop in any term within the Nernst equation.

The Q term relates to the activities of the reactants and products at equilibrium.